# Open a bootstrap modal from a controller after [Authorize] redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I use ASP.NET MVC 4, and I want to know if it's possible to open a bootstrap modal with ActionResult after a redirection due to [Authorize] attribute.
In Web.config I have this :

```
<Authentication mode="forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/home/login"/>
</Authentication>
```

My authentication form is in a bootstrap modal, in a normal way I use a link to open this modal, but in the case of a redirection due to [Authorize] attibute.

How I can open the modal to authenticate the user ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do it with Javascript when the page is ready maybe?

Comment: @JuliaWill Yes, but with which event ? I know how to open a modal with Javascript. My view should remain available when the user isn't authenticated. (I don't want to use timer) thx.